# Come back to same activity after using ACTION_VIEW android

Tags: android, webview

I used following code to post a tweet on twitter.

```
 String tweetUrl = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="+"Text to be posted".replace(" ", "%20")
                            + " https://www.someurl.com";
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(tweetUrl);

                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
```

It's working fine. But the problem is it stays back in the same page after the tweet is posted. How can i redirect back to same activity after tweet is sent?

Comment: this may help you, http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/communicating-between-activity-and-browser-callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch Mode should Help you out here. So, try to read [`this`](http://intridea.com/blog/2011/6/16/android-understanding-activity-launchmode) blog to get better idea.